# Iam getting this error object has no attribute. I want to merge excel files

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd

class mergeExcelFiles:   
    def _init_(self):
        try:
            self.df_mail_file=pd.read_excel(r"/E:mailfiletest.xlsx")
            self.df_mail_matrix=pd.read_excel(r"/E:mail_matrix.xlsx")
        except:
            print("files are not available")

    # Merge two excel files 
    def merge_files(self):
        df_mail_file=self.df_mail_file
        df_mail_matrix=self.df_mail_matrix
        
        if(len(df_mail_file )>0 &(len(df_mail_matrix)>0)):
            df=df_mail_file.merge(df_mail_matrix,on=['county','state'],how='outer')
        else:
            df=pd.DataFrame()
            
        return df

    # Data mainpulation as per the requirement
    def manipulate_data(self):
        data=self.merge_files()
        
        #apply filters and conditoins here 
       
        return data 
        
mergefile=mergeExcelFiles()
df_output=mergefile.manipulate_data()
df_output.head()
```

Comment: Can you please edit properly the format of your code and include the **entire error message**?

Comment: Dunder! I.e. `_init_` -> `__init__`.